# MS Edge incorrectly renders the page

Tags: cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I was faced with the fact that [our website](https://vc.ru/media/45872-yuriy-dud-ushel-s-posta-glavreda-sports-ru) doesn't work in MS Edge.
It can't fully render the page: you can see the gray stripes in the screenshot below.

[image]

In addition, after a while the page freezes and does not respond to any actions.
There's no any errors in console.
All my colleagues have a similar problem with Edge on this website.
Meanwhile, in Chrome, Safari and Firefox everything works fine.
Any ideas, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps and check whether it solve your issue or not.

(1) Press Windows key + X and open the Command Prompt (Admin).

(2) In the Command Prompt, type in Powershell and press Enter.

(3) Paste the following line into the PowerShell window and press Enter.

```html
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}
```

(4) Wait until it’s completed, and C:\Users\yourusername> will appear on the screen when the process is completed.

(5) Reboot your computer and try to open the Microsoft Edge again.